# There exists exactly one function satisfying $f(x)=x+\frac{1}{2}\sin(f(x))$ for all $x\in[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

Using the Banach fixed-point theorem, how do I prove that there exists exactly one continuous function $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb{R}$ that satisfies $$f(x)=x+\frac{1}{2}\sin(f(x))$$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

I'm currently doing some analysis problems for practice and I really don't know how to solve this. Thank you for any solutions or hints to this problem.

Comment: You should include more context. What does the Banach theorem say, and what would that look like in the situation at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be the Banach space $C([0,1])$ (continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$) with the usual norm
$$
\| f-g \| = \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)-g(x)|.
$$
Define $T: X \to X$ by
$$
(Tf)(x) = x + \frac12 \sin(f(x)).
$$
If we show that $T$ is a contraction, the Banach fixed point theorem implies that there is exactly one fixed point of $T$, which is what you want to prove.

We can estimate
\begin{align*}
\| Tf - Tg \| &= \sup_{x \in [0,1]} \left| x+ \frac12 \sin(f(x)) - \left( x + \frac12 \sin (g(x)) \right) \right| = \frac12 \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |\sin(f(x)) - \sin(g(x))| \\
&\leq \frac12 \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x) - g(x)| = \frac12 \| f-g \|.
\end{align*}
The inequality going from the first line to the second comes from the fact that $|\sin y - \sin z| \leq |y-z|$ for any real $y,z$ (this can be proved using the mean value theorem, for example).

Therefore $T$ is a contraction mapping as desired.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So if I understand correctly, looking at the definition of Banach fixed point theorem, i.e. for a contraction $T$: $T(x^*)=x^*$, where $x^*\in X$ is unique, here $f(x)$ is our $x^*$ so to speak and so it is unique. This really helped me understand this topic a bit better